# HTML5 Audio playback stops at 33 minutes on iOS

Tags: ios, html, audio

I'm using the standard HTML audio tag to play an mp3 file on a webpage. The file is a podcast so it's up to an hour long. Playback is absolutely fine until 33 minutes in. Then it stops, and nothing but a page refresh will get it to start playing again.

So far the problem is only happening on iOS, both Safari and Chrome. Desktop browsers work fine. The files are coming from an Amazon Cloudfront instance so they arrive pretty quick.

At first I thought this may be a connection issue, but I've found that it persists on both 3G and wi-fi connections. I haven't experienced any other issues at all with loading the audio and playing it back, only that it stops at 33 minutes regardless of file size, or time length.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it happening with only one file, or does it happen with files from different sources?

Comment: It' happening on all files that I post using the audio tag. We're a podcast network and use the podpress plugin. Any files which are shown via that plugin, play perfectly all the way through, and display using the same default safari audio player on iOS.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm experiencing a very similar problem... "only on iOS, both Safari and Chrome" regardless of where the file is served from. Although in my case the audio restarts after a few minutes (of a 30 minute mp3 audio file).